# Error on Goto function on playwright when navigate to PDF file

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have this link https://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br/contrib/app/nfse/rel/rp_nfse_v23.aspx?s=61154301&e=00165960000101&f=2BED3D1E8 (if you try to access its gonna ask to solve a captcha but as long as i already have the session, the playwright doesnt need to worry it).

```
OUT page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br/contrib/app/nfse/rel/rp_nfse_v23.aspx?s=61154301&e=00165960000101&f=2BED3D1E8
```

Anybody knows why playwright cannot access it? I need to download the PDF Buffer of this link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fetch` API. Something like this:

```
const fetchResponse = browserContect.request.get('https://nfse.blumenau.sc.gov.br/contrib/app/nfse/rel/rp_nfse_v23.aspx?s=61154301&e=00165960000101&f=2BED3D1E8')
const pdfBuffer = await fetchResponse.body();
```

Comment: The problem with that is that i would need to insert the cookie on it.

Im trying that using got module but it doesnt work either.

Comment: This will use the cookies from your browser context.

Comment: Ah, now i got it. Yeah, your right, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found a Solution:

First i didnt concatenate the cookie on the calling of the function

```
const cook = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=' + cookie;    
await setCookie(cook, urlFinal);
```

Then i used the got module to put the cookie and get the buffer of the pdf:

```
response = await got(urlFinal, {cookieJar}).buffer();
```

Plus: Sometimes it returned a blank pdf (i think because of the timeout of loading it). So i inserted a loop to check the size of the buffer and tried 20 times until it gets more than 'X' of lenght.

```
for (let j = 0;j<=25;j++){
                                console.log('Entrei no looping ==> ' + j);
                                response = await got(urlFinal, {cookieJar}).buffer();
                                if (response.toString().length>=10000){
                                    j=21;
                                }
                            }
                            console.log('tamanho do buffer ==> ' + response.toString().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that already but didnt work either:

```
const cookie = (await page.context().cookies()).filter(cookie => cookie.name === 'ASP.NET_SessionId')
                                               .map(cookie => cookie.value)[0];
console.log(cookie);
const cookieJar = new CookieJar();
const setCookie = promisify(cookieJar.setCookie.bind(cookieJar));

await setCookie('ASP.NET_SessionId=' + cookie, urlFinal);

const response = await got(urlFinal, {cookieJar}).buffer();
```

its really a challenge. Because if i wont go with page.goto i loose the session. The code bellow would solve the problem.

```
await page.goto(urlFinal);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).